# How to create Mockito objects for void method?

Tags: mockito

I am new to Mockito Testing

I want to test my JMS Client,in Jms client one **void** method is there

```
@Override
public void sendMessage(Serializable message) {

    Connection conn = null;

    Session session = null;

    try {
        conn = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        session = conn.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
        Message msg = null;
        if (message instanceof String) {
            msg = session.createTextMessage();
            ((TextMessage) msg).setText((String) message); 
        } else {
            msg = session.createObjectMessage();
            ((ObjectMessage) msg).setObject(message);
        }
        producer.send(msg);
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            log.debug("Successfully sent JMS message. Message: "
                + message.toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Failed to send JMS message. ErrMsg: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        if (session != null) try { session.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
        if (conn != null) try { conn.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

How to create mock objects for void methods like that

```
public void sendMessage(Serializable message)
```

I wrote the test case for void method() using mock object is it correct are wrong anybody please let me know

```
public class SmsResourceTest {

    private SmsResource smsResource;
    private JmsClient jmsclient;

    @Before
        public void setUp()throws Exception{
        smsResource = new SmsResource();
        jmsclient = mock(JmsClientImpl.class);

    }
    @After
    public void tearDown()throws Exception{
        smsResource=null;
        jmsclient=null;

    }

    @Test
    public void testSendSms()throws Exception{

        SmsNotificationDTO sms = new SmsNotificationDTO();
        sms.setMessage("Sending Messages...");
        try{

            doNothing().doThrow(new RuntimeException())
                .when(jmsclient).sendMessage(sms);
            String output = sms.toString();
            System.out.println(output);

            smsResource.init();
            Response res = smsResource.sendSms(null, sms);
            Assert.assertEquals(200,res.getStatus());
            System.out.println("response...... "+res.getStatus());
        }catch(Exception e){
            Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
        }
    }   
}
```

Please help me...

Comment: There is a lot going on inside the method sendMessage. First of all, do you want to do an integration test or a unit test?

Comment: Yes, that appears to be correct, but in the future please use [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) as that is a better home for reviewing large blocks of already-written code. Cheers!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on the Code Review site.

Comment: Just a couple of comments. (1) You don't need the `try/catch/Assert.fail` because JUnit will automatically cause a test to fail if there's an uncaught exception.  (2) You can use `verify` to ensure that a method on a mock has only been called once - it's a bit more readable than `doNothing().doThrow(...)`.

Comment: And I really don't understand what the question is - you've asked how to do something, then given code that does it.  Is there something you need to know?